# TYPO3 get pages by sys_categor(y/ies)

Tags: sql, typo3, typoscript

I need your help, I do not see the forest for the trees.
Consider the following scenario:

A TYPO3 - system with, say, 2 pages. (About us & Services)
Furthermore, I have 3 System Categories (Cat 1, Cat 2 Cat 3)

The page About us, the categories "Cat 1" & "Cat 2".
The page Services has the categories "Cat 2" & "Cat 3".

Now I need a SELECT query in typoscript from which I get only the page which "Cat 3" and "Cat 2 (In this case it would be the page Services).

But let's start with simple SQL and not with a Typoscript query.

The following 3 tables exist in TYPO3 for this situation:

"pages", "sys_category", "sys_category_record_mm"

```
pages - table:
+-----+----------+------------+
| uid |  title   | categories |
+-----+----------+------------+
|   3 | About us |          2 |
|   4 | Services |          2 |
+-----+----------+------------+


sys_category - table:
+-----+-------+
| uid | title |
+-----+-------+
|   1 | Cat 1 |
|   2 | Cat 2 |
|   3 | Cat 3 |
+-----+-------+


sys_category_record_mm - table:
+-----------+-------------+------------+
| uid_local | uid_foreign | tablenames |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
|         2 |           4 | pages      |
|         2 |           3 | pages      |
|         1 |           4 | pages      |
|         3 |           3 | pages      |
+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Now i have a simple sql query which outputs all pages who got a category, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT title FROM pages
JOIN sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = pages.uid
WHERE sys_category_record_mm.tablenames = 'pages'
```

This will get me following output:

```
+----------+
|  title   |
+----------+
| Services |
| About us |
+----------+
```

But now I want to have only the page "Services" which has category "Cat 2" and category "Cat 3".

How I have to modify my query to get only the page with both categories.

I tried something like that but i know that this can't work, because I will still get both pages because of the OR condition.

```
SELECT DISTINCT title FROM pages
JOIN sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = pages.uid
WHERE sys_category_record_mm.tablenames = 'pages' AND (sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = 2 OR sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = 3)
```

Thanks in advance!!

I'm thankful for every tip.

Comment: Did you check https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html#special-categories . The value "_categories" contains all categories as a comma separated list. Maybe you can use this with a stdWrap.if to render only the pages belonging to the required categories.

Comment: It is a good idea. I already saw the categories menu but i wouldnt know how to exclude pages without all given categories with an if condition.. Its nearly the same problem like I have with my sql query.

Comment: You pointed me to the solutions! Thanks Marcus.. It is so easy with the categories menu .. I will add the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Marcus Schwemer, who pointed me to the solutions..
Thanks to pgampe for you answer!

I've done it with a categories menu.
Like Marcus said: "Each in the resulting array of pages gets an additional entry with key _categories containing the list of categories the page belongs to, as a comma-separated list of uid’s. It can be accessed with stdWrap.field or getText like any other field."

Its easy to do a if condition in the menu like:

```
20 = HMENU
20 {
    special = categories
    # Show all pages with categories 1, 2 and 3
    special.value = 1,2,3
    1 = TMENU
    1.NO {
        # get comma-separated list of uid's of the categories the page belongs to
        stdWrap.field = _categories
        # check the _categories field if it contains the categories you need.
        stdWrap.if {
            value = 2,3
            equals.field = _categories
        }
    }
}
```

That's all...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `GROUP BY` to limit your query to rows having a certain uid and then use having to only select those rows from the group that match your condition.

---

Consider the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pages.title, uid_local, uid_foreign FROM pages
JOIN sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = pages.uid
WHERE sys_category_record_mm.tablenames = 'pages'
```

Giving this result

```
+----------+-----------+-------------+
| title    | uid_local | uid_foreign |
+----------+-----------+-------------+
| Services | 2         | 53          | 
| Services | 3         | 53          |
| About Us | 1         | 54          |
| About Us | 2         | 54          |
+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT pages.title FROM pages
JOIN sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = pages.uid
WHERE sys_category_record_mm.tablenames = 'pages'
GROUP BY sys_category_record_mm.uid_local
HAVING sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = 2 or sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = 3
```

This gives me

```
+--------+
|Title   |
+--------+
|Services|
+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but If I exec the query with "HAVING sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = 1 OR sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = 2" I am still getting wrong results.. The expected result would be "Services" but i am getting "Services & About us" .. Any ideas?